# NAS backup - multiple machines

Tags: backup, network-attached-storage

HI

We are looking to backup between 50-100 servers to a NAS box each night (Contains of each server ie files and folders).

We need the backup application to backup to a NAS and perform incremental backups following the full backup. We also need to be able to store versions of each file. The full backup will probably be about 5TB.

Does anyone know a a cheap or free application which will do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

rsync and then instance files server side on a schedule of your choice.

Comment: Well we we thinking about using rsync to a QNAp rsync server however our servers are windows and there are not any good rsync tools for Windows which also version files?

Answer (score 1):

bacula should be able to do this, from what i understand of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [dirvish](http://www.dirvish.org) . It's easy to use, open source and it's based on rsync. I use it to make backups of 4 servers and 6 workstations, 20 TB of data. We have been using it the last 4 years without any problems.

Using hard links you have each file only copied once to your backup, and hard linked to newer directories, so you see at 2011-02-25/tree/etc/your_nice_config_file either a new file copied last night or a hard link to a previously copied file that didn't change from last backup.
Nice is that you always have all files, not only the new ones. And when you are running out of space you go and remove for example 2010-11-* .