# Server backup to NAS

Tags: windows, backup

HI

We are looking to backup the files from 50 windows servers (about 3TB) to a qnap NAS box over 1GB network.

Does anyone know of a good versioning app which will run on Windows and backup to the NAS or rsync server?

The app needs tobe able to perform incremental backups following the full backup and also versioning of the files.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [NAS backup - multiple machines](http://serverfault.com/questions/240290/nas-backup-multiple-machines)

Comment: no need to post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most standard backup applications will do exactly this. You may be able to use an open source tool to perform this. Your requirements are not listed other than needing full and incremental backups, so here's a list of Windows backup apps to pick from:

- [Amanda Backup](http://www.amanda.org/) (FOSS)
- [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/) (FOSS)
- [Zmanda Enterprise backup](http://www.zmanda.com/amanda-enterprise-edition.html) (Commercial)
- [Symantec Backup Exec](http://www.symantec.com/business/products/family.jsp?familyid=backupexec) (Commercial)
- [FalconStor](http://www.falconstor.com/) (Commercial - lots of products)
- [Novastor](http://www.novastor.com/) (Commerecial)

And the list could go on, and on, and on...

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provide an excellent system called Microsoft Data Protection Manager [Link to site](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/data-protection-manager.aspx)
It works for most schools I consult to, who run over 1500 laptops, around 30 plus servers and 100's of desktops. Provides, backup, recover, system restore and more to many many different types of storage systems.

Can't fault it, easy to setup and runs brilliantly. I have worked with NetApp, ZFS and others and it wins.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows schedtask to schedule a backup.  I recommend using [robocopy.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) from the Windows Resource Kit.

Be aware to be very careful with how you use this command, but here is an example:

```
@echo off
::  ---------------------------------------------------------------
::  The previous command will copy the content of d:\inetpub\wwwroot and 
::  push it to the remote server's d:\inetpub\wwwroot.
::  ---------------------------------------------------------------
::  Uses robocopy.exe from C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools
::  ---------------------------------------------------------------
::  /E = copies all subdirectories including empty ones
::  /PURGE = deletes destination files/folders that no longer exist in the source
::  /SEC = copies the security permissions (ACL) of the files to the destination location
::  /NP =  turns off the copy progress bar; DEFINITELY do this if you are logging the results
::  /NJH = don't log the job header
::  /NJS = don't log the job summary
::  /XF = exclude copying specific files (e.g. keepalive_*.*)
::  /XD = exclude copying specific folders (e.g. trigger)
::  /R =  specifies number of times to retry if the copy fails (e.g. 5)
::  /COPYALL = copies everything: data, attributes, timestamps, security, ownership and 
::        auditing information; overkill really since I specified /SEC
::  /LOG = log results to the specified log file (e.g. copy_to_webserver1.log)
::  ---------------------------------------------------------------

:: change wait timeout to 1 second and set it to default in registry
:: robocopy D:\ E:\ /r:1 /w:1 /reg

robocopy.exe D:\inetpub\wwwroot\ \\webserver1\D$\inetpub\wwwroot\ *.* /E /PURGE /SEC /NP /NJH /NJS /XF keepalive_*.* /XD trigger /XD "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Long Path Name" /R:5 /COPYALL /LOG:copy_to_webserver1.log
```