# Dropbox alternative with NAS

Tags: backup, dropbox

HI

Does anyone know how we can backup some files and folders from windows machine to a nas (To store versions of files ie incremental backups) Then sync the data on the nas to another Windows PC for an off-site copy?

Basically Dropbox with our own NAS and control?

Comment: I love it when someone uses Dropbox as an example of simple LAN management.  You just want a simple file share on your NAS with some type of backup solution.  Your backup can be as simple as a scheduled task that runs to xcopy files around.

Comment: you already have two questions open on this same topic. Please go back and deal with those before posting duplicate questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NAS backup - multiple machines](http://serverfault.com/questions/240290/nas-backup-multiple-machines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions available, depening on your exact needs.

As I understand, you do not have a server machine for NAS, just plain file server. In this case for free solution to keeping files in sync you might adapt a distributed kind of version control system (VCS), which does not require a server, such as [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

There is some overhead to using a VCS compared to some kind of specialized backup/sync software, however, there are some upsides too, which might be useful to you, depending on your exact needs (keeping info on previous versions of files, for example).